# Why do you say "People Management" ("people" is plural) but not "Person Management" ("person" is singular)?

Tags: singular-vs-plural, compound-nouns

When it comes to a noun + noun compound, the former is usually in its singular form. But why do you say "people management", not "person management"? If this is about managing a group of people, not a single person, then why you say ["animal management"](https://www.aza.org/animal-management?locale=en), not "animals management"?

Answer (score 1):

I think this comes from animals being seen as something you have a quantity of (think "bucket of sand" vs "bucket of sands") whereas people like to be seen as individuals, and not a collective mass of person.

If you are a "fun" kind of manager though, with just one person that you manage, you could say that you are in the business of "person management".